# Only allow Android and Iphone App to call my server

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, iphone, security

I have a ASP.NET/IIS server. I want to restrict my server to only accept request from Android and Iphone(IOS) applications. I have heard about HMAC. Can HMAC help me?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp, thanks. Any way to reduce or make it harder?

Comment: Assuming apps are in your control, add a param in web requests parameters asking about hardware/software info of devices making requests and you can handle only required requests.

Comment: @SalmanZaidi and how will this address replay attacks?

Comment: @user960567 potentially you can employ challenge/response techniques with a complex algorithm used to calculate response on the device. This will protect from replay attacks. Still the hacker will be able to disassemble your application and pick the code that calculates the response from it.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp thanks for your valuebale response